# Grabbing number next to a dollar sign with optional thousands and decimals

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab a number that can be in the format $5,000.23 as well as say, $22.43 or $3,000

Here's my regular expression, this is in PHP.

```
preg_match('/\$([0-9]+)([\.,]*)?([0-9]*)?([\.])?([0-9]*)?/', $blah, $blah2);
```

It seems to match numbers in the format $5,500.23 perfectly fine, however it doesn't seem to match any other numbers well, like $0.

How do I make everything optional? Shouldn't grouping () and using a question mark do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\$[\d,.]*[\d]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/toY0qdVNUmv0kC-K)

---

***Specific PHP Example:***

```
$re = "/\\$[\\d,.]*[\\d]/"; 
$str = "\$1 klsjdfgsjdfg \$100 kjdfhglsjdfg \$1,000 jljsdfg \$1,000.00 ldfjhsdf"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX2aG7/1)

Comment: Yep, this seems to do the trick. And a lot simpler than mine. I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: No worries - interestingly, this is the 3rd time I've answered this question today on different sites. Is it a significant time in the US for finance?

Comment: You might want to use single quotes then you won't need the escaping.

Comment: This is for a fast food company, so at least not in this case, @MacroMan.

Comment: @chris85 I know - it was copy/pasted from the Regex101 code builder and on my mobile so cba. Feel free to change it if it bothers you.